# How to test a contract with multiple wallets?

Tags: solidity, wallets, testing

I would like to generate N wallets with ether, using `ethers`.

After that, I would like each of these wallets to interact with the functions of the contract.

**How can I do this?**

**TEST**

```
describe("Vote Count", () => {
    const SIGNERS: SignerWithAddress[] = [];

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const SIGNERS_WITH_ADDRESS = await ethers.getSigners();
        SIGNERS.push(SIGNERS_WITH_ADDRESS[1]);
    });
});
```

**CONTRACT**

```
contract Ballot is IHelper, Guard, Logging {
    Confirmed[6] private _confirmedVotes;
    Abstention private _abstentionVotes;
    uint[6] private _candidates;
    uint private _totalConfirmedVotes;
    mapping(address => bool) private _electorHasAlreadyVoted;

    constructor() {}

    function getResult() public view returns (ElectionResult memory) {
        return
            ElectionResult({
                candidates: _candidates,
                totalConfirmedVotes: _totalConfirmedVotes,
                confirmedVotes: _confirmedVotes,
                abstentionVotes: _abstentionVotes
            });
    }

    function confirmVote(uint candidateID)
        public
        onlyCandidateRegistered(candidateID, _candidates.length)
        onlyElectorWhoDidNotVote(_electorHasAlreadyVoted[msg.sender])
    {
        _totalConfirmedVotes++;

        _confirmedVotes[candidateID].elector.push(msg.sender);
        _confirmedVotes[candidateID].candidate = candidateID;
        _confirmedVotes[candidateID].vote.total++;

        _electorHasAlreadyVoted[msg.sender] = true;

        emit LogElectorVote("Vote confirmed and computed!", getResult());
    }

    function abstentionVote() public onlyElectorWhoDidNotVote(_electorHasAlreadyVoted[msg.sender]) {
        _abstentionVotes.elector.push(msg.sender);
        _abstentionVotes.vote.total++;

        _electorHasAlreadyVoted[msg.sender] = true;

        emit LogElectorVote("Vote confirmed and computed!", getResult());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:  connect your provider to ethers to generate the wallets:

```typescript
it("should succeed - make a 100 signers and all of them have balance 0", async () => {
        let addressArray: string[] = [];
        let signers: Wallet[] = [];
        const startingBalance = ethers.utils.parseEther("10000");

        //create 100 wallets
        for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
          //create a new wallet
          let wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom().connect(ethers.provider);
          //can store as signer
          signers.push(wallet);
          //can store as address
          addressArray.push(wallet.address.toString());
        }

        await helpers.mine(1);

        //fund them
        const fundThem = () => {
          return Promise.all(
            addressArray.map(async fooWallet => {

              expect(await helpers.setBalance(fooWallet, startingBalance)).to.changeEtherBalance(fooWallet, startingBalance);
              console.log(`funded: ${fooWallet}`);

            })
          ).then(() => {
            console.log("done");
          });
        };
        await fundThem();

        //Use it as a signer
        const checkTheirNFT = () => {
          return Promise.all(
            signers.map(async fooSigner => {
              expect(await yourNFTContract.connect(fooSigner).balanceOf(fooSigner.address, 1)).to.be.equal(0);
              console.log(`fooWallet: ${fooSigner.address}`);
            })
          ).then(() => {
            console.log("done");
          });
        };
        await checkTheirNFT();

        //Profit
      });
```

It took me a while but here :D the knowledge is for everyone!

what is helpers.setBalance? [HArdhat helper](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/overview)

**EDIT_EDIT_EDIT_EDIT**

Refactor code to use Promises instead of await inside a for loop

Thanks Tiago for pointing this out! using Promise.All happened to perform better for testing thousands of transactions in short time than await inside a loop

Comment: this works perfectly in a local hardhat node ;) it will not work on testnets

Comment: The logic is correct, however you can't put await inside a for, correct it for PromiseAll and I'll give your answer as exact.

Comment: can you provide an example of how it would go? or would you mind refactoring my code in an extra answer? I am not very good at Typescript and this code does fulfill my needs :c

Comment: I don't know exactly either, it would look something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: I actually ran into some issues trying to use promises; The execution of the code keeps when a call to the blockchain is not complete;  Take a look at this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140198/how-to-properly-use-promises-in-loop-contract-calls-when-testing I made a question regarding this >.<

Comment: Problem solved! haha using Promise.All did the trick! now it is actually faster! thanks!